# Express + nodeJS never get my static file

Tags: css, node.js, express

I can't understand why express can't get my static file for display my css.

express.js :

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

style.css

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-image: url("background.jpg");
} </style>
```

test.ejs :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <body>
<h1> TEST </h1> </body> </html>
```

folder path :

```
/express.js
/public/style.css
/public/background.jpg
/views/test.ejs
```

test.ejs route :

```
.get('/myTest', function(req, res){
res.render('test.ejs', { data: req.session.info });
})
```

(info is an array of data for the current session)

Comment: What is the route that is rendering `test.ejs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was tired...unfortunatly It was the 1rst line of my css... 
delete `<style> </style balise`

Answer (score 0):

test.ejs should be

```
<html> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
<h1> TEST </h1 </body> </html>
```

hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thank for your anwser A-0, No, anything is displayed...the only time where the css works, is when i put it directly in .ejs file, but it's dirty. (and its not working with picture, only if i write "background-color: black;"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a relative path in your CSS from an absolute path other than `/`. So when you request `/myTest`, the browser is looking for `/myTest/background.jpg` which of course 404s because it really should be `/background.jpg` according to your filesystem layout.

One easy way to fix this is to make your CSS urls absolute:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("/background.jpg");
}
```

Comment: It's not working...i've no idea why. If I put color in my css file, it works well, my picture path must be still wrong...